# ISCmdBld.exe ---- Not replacing latest file during Build

Tags: installshield

I am developing a tool which will automate the installshield (2008 Primer Version) setup (project type InstallScript MSI). The input files have been referenced directly from the Drop Location which will copy all the files after build that from Team Foundation Server (TFS).

Next from batch file i am calling the ISCmdBld.exe which will build the Installshield project through command line.

When i initiated the build i came across that file versions are older in Installshield editor as well as in Release Folder, where as in Drop Location of TFS it is latest version. How do i refresh the File list of Installshield programmatically or is there any solution available.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have set hard references to a drop folder whose path changes with every build.

In our builds, I map a W:\ drive to our current drop folder using the following command:

```
 <!-- Map the W drive to the current drop's release folder -->
<Exec Command="&quot;c:\pstools\psexec.exe&quot; -s -accepteula subst w: &quot;$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Release&quot;" ContinueOnError="false" />
```

Then, I went into my install project and under the Path Variables view, I changed the reference path to W.

This requires PsExec, which is a free utility from Microsoft: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

At the end of the build, I unmap the W drive, so the next build can run without an error:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;c:\pstools\psexec.exe&quot; -s -accepteula subst w: /D" ContinueOnError="true" />
```